# Craft “Embedded Assets” Plug-in didn't save Embed in selected Asset Volume in CP

Tags: assets, plugin-embeddedassets

i have 3 asset volumes in my craft install (3.1.5). If i want to create an embedded asset(Embedded Assets Plugin 1.0.2) in the first volume (CP) in my volume List than it appears in the second. Every Embed Asset appears in the second Volume!
What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this: https://github.com/spicywebau/craft-embedded-assets/issues/95

Might be related and a fix is expected in Monday.

Comment: Thx - Yes, i read it. Hope the fix solve this problem.

Comment: It Works perfect with the new Version https://github.com/spicywebau/craft-embedded-assets 2.0.0